# How to Remove Specific Dimenstion Image in Wordpress

Tags: image

I am searching to solve this issue for 3 hours. my theme is generating such images which i don't need. i am trying to get support but answer is not coming. can someone please tell me

> How can i stop generating (one or more) specific dimension images to
>   save my bandwidth. i am not asking about the default images of
>   wordpress like medium, full or small. and also i am not thinking to
>   remove code.

i just need a code which i put on my site (probably in functions.php file) which can stop generating images of a specific dimensions.

Comment: Those thumbnails with specific dimensions are being defined by your theme. All you need to do is locate the function that is generating those sizes and remove them. Usually these functions are stored in functions.php in the root directory of the theme, but not always. The function you're looking for starts with this: `add_image_size`. After you've removed the functions, you can regenerate your thumbnails to remove the ones generated by the custom function.

Comment: i don't wanna remove any code in functions file
i want a code which can stop to generate a specific dimension image

Comment: Well then you'll just have to live with it.